I have problem with Vuforia Area Target after building the apk, showing nothing
I am new in Unity and Vuforia. Right now i am trying to create AR with area target. I have followed the instruction and video example in youtube. Starting with create Area Target with Vuforia Area Creator in IPAD. But when i built it to Android, nothing is shown.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHqwmhVhWKQ
Can you share your experiences about what kind of problems that usually appear when we create Area Target AR application?
Can we use Area Target for outdoor because that is what i am trying to do?
Is different lighting / brighness affecting the result of AR?
enter image description here
Thank you for the sharing.

Have you tested your target in the Creator app itself? The steps are the same as testing a Model Target https://developer.vuforia.com/library/tools/creator-app#model-targets .  To test on Android you can use this other app https://developer.vuforia.com/library/develop-area-targets/area-targets-test-app-user-guide . With this test you should be able to rule out target-related issues,

Also you might want to go through this troubleshooting guide here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-your-app
